# @ngrx/store@11.0.0 Error during template compile of 'StoreModule'

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store, angular11

so I've update `@ngrx` to its latest releases this morning:

```json
-   "@ngrx/effects": "10.1.2",
-   "@ngrx/router-store": "10.1.2",
-   "@ngrx/store": "10.1.2",
+   "@ngrx/effects": "11.0.0",
+   "@ngrx/router-store": "11.0.0",
+   "@ngrx/store": "11.0.0",
```

`@angular/core` has already been migrated to `@^11.0.0` before, everything worked well with `@ngrx/store@10.1.2`. despite the invalid `peerDependency`, of course.

now my build (`ng build [PROJECT_NAME]`) got stuck throwing errors:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: @ngrx/store/ngrx-store.ts(224,21): Error during template compile of 'StoreModule'
  Expression form not supported.
@ngrx/store/ngrx-store.ts(231,15): Error during template compile of 'StoreModule'
  Expression form not supported.
@ngrx/store/ngrx-store.ts(257,13): Error during template compile of 'StoreModule'
  Expression form not supported.
@ngrx/store/ngrx-store.ts(224,21): Error during template compile of 'StoreModule'
  Expression form not supported.
@ngrx/store/ngrx-store.ts(231,15): Error during template compile of 'StoreModule'
  Expression form not supported.
@ngrx/store/ngrx-store.ts(257,13): Error during template compile of 'StoreModule'
  Expression form not supported.
```

I've already figured out, that the cause is somehow related to `StoreModule.forFeature('auth', reducers)` which I import in a submodule. the root `AppModule` imports `StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers }),`. I cannot really find an error, feature reducers combined as following:

```
export interface AuthStateData {
  status: fromAuth.AuthStateData;
  loginPage: fromLoginPage.LoginStateData;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<AuthStateData> = {
  status: fromAuth.reducer,
  loginPage: fromLoginPage.reducer
};
```

has anyone experienced similar issues? and in the best case found a solution?

no, (sadly) my code is not open sourced.

Comment: I just reported the same issue to the ngrx team: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2919#issuecomment-776888606 I just downgraded to v10 to keep my project running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, it was a bug after all :)

report: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2919 
fix: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/pull/2922